# POST request with bearer token not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, auth0

My code to get access token is :

```
string request = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&audience={2}"
                            , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(APIRequestConstants.ClientId), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(APIRequestConstants.ClientSecret), "aws-dev-api");
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(result);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                    {
                        return res.access_token.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

It is giving the access token correctly. But when I post this access token with Post request to a url then it given the status as forbidden with 403 & content message as Not Authorized to perform this action.

Same code when I deploy then it gives me exception as below:

Error in MakePostRequest =

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1.get_Result()
>      at APIConstants.APIRequests.MakePostRequest(String url, String token, Lead lead) in E:\APIRequests.cs:line 64
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.<---

My Code for making Post request is :

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lead), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response2 = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string result = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Same thing when I run via Postman it's working very fine.
Please someone help me out of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the headers tab look like in your Postman request?

Comment: Please find the screenshots of the header tab as it looks in postman.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_wjs9YwKQ3VEE0WmM1RXgySjQ/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz_wjs9YwKQ3bUFBMS05dGxrQVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A TaskCanceledException, in the context of an HttpClient Request, can indicate that your request has timed out.

Can you confirm that the url you are passing to PostAsync(url has been set correctly and is the endpoint you expect. Try running a tool like Fiddler to inspect the traffic you are generating, is the request being sent correct?

Comment: Thank you Dylan... The URL which I was using for the POST request was http, but I needed to POST via https. Problem has been resolved.